# How to get references from a .csproj file?

Tags: c#, xml, csproj

I want to combine two different .csproj files into one project. Therefore I must select one of it as a "host" and migrate the other project into it. For that, I need to get the references inside of one .csproj file and write that into the other ("host") .csproj file.
What would be the best way to achieve this programmatically in WPF?

I tried creating a class from the xml of the .csproj file using an online converting tool. Then deserializing it via an XML Deserializer, but that didn't work.
I also read that you can use MSBuild, but I couldn't really find good examples on it similiar to my case.

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Xml2CSharp.Project));
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(SelectedHostProject.Path, FileMode.Open))
{
    XMLProject result = (XMLProject)ser.Deserialize(fileStream);
    references.Add(result);
}
```

and here is my converted csproj file:

```
namespace Xml2CSharp
{
   [Serializable]
   public class Import
   {
       public string Project { get; set; }

       public string Condition { get; set; }
   }

   [Serializable]
   public class Configuration
   {
       public string Condition { get; set; }

       public string Text { get; set; }
   }


   [Serializable]
   public class Platform
   {
       public string Condition { get; set; }

       public string Text { get; set; }
   }

   [Serializable]
   public class PropertyGroup
   {
       public Configuration Configuration { get; set; }

       public Platform Platform { get; set; }

       public string ProjectGuid { get; set; }

       public string OutputType { get; set; }

       public string AppDesignerFolder { get; set; }

       public string RootNamespace { get; set; }

       public string AssemblyName { get; set; }

       public string TargetFrameworkVersion { get; set; }

       public string FileAlignment { get; set; }

       public string AutoGenerateBindingRedirects { get; set; }

       public string SccProjectName { get; set; }

       public string SccLocalPath { get; set; }

       public string SccAuxPath { get; set; }

       public string SccProvider { get; set; }

       public string PlatformTarget { get; set; }

       public string DebugSymbols { get; set; }

       public string DebugType { get; set; }

       public string Optimize { get; set; }

       public string OutputPath { get; set; }

       public string DefineConstants { get; set; }

       public string ErrorReport { get; set; }

       public string WarningLevel { get; set; }

       public string Condition { get; set; }

       public string SignAssembly { get; set; }

       public string AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile { get; set; }
  }

[Serializable]
public class Reference
{
    public string HintPath { get; set; }
    public string Include { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ItemGroup
{
    public List<Reference> Reference { get; set; }

    public List<Compile> Compile { get; set; }

    public None None { get; set; }

    public EmbeddedResource EmbeddedResource { get; set; }

    public ProjectReference ProjectReference { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Compile
{
    public string SubType { get; set; }

    public string Include { get; set; }

    public string DependentUpon { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class None
{
    public string Include { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class EmbeddedResource
{
    public string DependentUpon { get; set; }

    public string Include { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class ProjectReference
{
    public string Project { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Include { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Project
{
    public List<Import> Import { get; set; }

    public List<PropertyGroup> PropertyGroup { get; set; }

    public List<ItemGroup> ItemGroup { get; set; }

    public string ToolsVersion { get; set; }

    public string DefaultTargets { get; set; }

    public string Xmlns { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: This sounds like the long way around.

Comment: T reference another project you need to add from Menu : Project : Add Existing Item.  Then browse to where 2nd project is located and select executable (either dll or exe) from project bin folder (I usually use the one in the debug folder).  When doing this the 2nd project executable is automatically copied to the 1st project bin folder.  Then add a "USING" statement to top of 1st project module with the namespace of 2nd project

Comment: Maybe I should have said, that I need to do it programmatically, because I want to do it in a loop for a lot of project files. Not for just one use. My goal is to have application that combines projects.